# Selenium - select an element according to another element

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I use Selenium and Java, and I need to write a selector for a table where I need to find the exact column and right-click on it. The problem is that it's simple to find the column by using the lstype as they all have different values, but it's not possible to right-click on it. Because of that, I need to click on the box directly under it.

This is approximately what the table looks like:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WtFw.png)

And this is approximately what the html looks like:

```
<div class="head">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="game" lstype="124"></td>
                <td class="game" lstype="245"></td>
                <td class="game" lstype="873"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <table id="extractBody">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="game"></td>
                <td class="game"></td>
                <td class="game"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Each of the td in the first part refer to the header box (green) and each of the td in the second part are the elements I can actually click on.

I don't know how to get the below boxes according to lstype that's in the header boxes.
I've posted it as only 3 columns, but there are many more in reality. Same with rows.

I would appreciate any help. I guess it should be done with xpaths, but nothing I've tried has worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume you can first select the row using some xpath. Since you have not shown any info about the rows, I would assume it is sorted out. Then on the row object I would use the below XPath

```
.//table[@id='extractBody']//tr/td[count(//td[@lstype='124']/preceding-sibling::td) + 1]
```

The way this works is, below xpath

```
count(//td[@lstype='124']/preceding-sibling::td) + 1
```

Count of TD elements before your current node, so if your node is 2nd node this gives 1 and then we add 1 to it to get our column number. Then we use

```
.//table[@id='extractBody']//tr/td[desiredcount]
```

To get the element on that index, and then you can click on it

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways of doing it 1 is using this plugin [mozzila plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/), it will record all the movements and clicks and events and then, when you finish you have the option to export it on the way that you want, for example on java class.

the other way is simple put some unique identifiers on every checkbox on the body element, call it and that sould be done, by using xpath is complicated but is you find that the other 2 options fails, you must apply xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the simplest way is to find all of the td elements with the class game

```
List<WebElement> foo = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.game");
```

Then cycle through the elements until you find the one you want, and add that index to half of the size of the whole list, and then click on that element

```
int count =0;
for(WebElement ele: foo){
if (ele.getAttribute("lstype").equals({searchTerm}) {
  foo.get(count+(foo.size()/2)).click()
}
count++
}
```

This is obviously presuming there are equal numbers of elements in both tables